# how to show keypad below textfield in nativescript using modalStack?

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

If I click on the textfield then keypad is open above the that field in modalstack of nativescript.
that's why textfield cannot display when fill that textfield..
First pic will show you before the click on the textfield
Second pic will show after click on the textfield.[image: before the click on the textfield]

[image: after click on the textfield]

Comment: Use [nativescript-keyboard-toolbar](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-keyboard-toolbar).

Comment: sorry, but this is not a proper solution. Can you give any other solution..

Comment: That depends on what kind of application or UX you are expecting. The keyboard manager just attaches kind of scroll view on the parent and lets you move. I presumed you wouldn't want your list view to move away when keyboard is shown more like how chat window works. Anyways if you feel keyboard manager works better then it is.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this plugin for textfield move on open the keypad. https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-iqkeyboardmanager-ns